# Why would an app start redirecting to the home page?

Tags: redirect, iframe, fbml

At some point recently (i.e. this month), our Facebook app has started redirecting to https://www.facebook.com/home.php instead of loading the app.  The app was originally created as an FBML canvas app, but we converted it to an iframe canvas app (or at least we thought we did) before the June 5th deadline (it says iframe in the Facebook developers app under Canvas FBML/iframe).

I have confirmed that the app was up any running as of the 24th of July, so we made it past the July 5th end date for FBML.

Comment: Are you sure it's setup as an iframe app, has a callback and secure callback URL, isn't restricted or in sandbox mode, etc?

Comment: @Igy No clue, the app was developed by someone else who no longer works here.  I am only vaguely aware of how it works and have almost no knowlege of Facebook.  We made our changes to make it an iframe app at the end of May and it kept working.  It only started redirecting this month (I am trying to nail down the date with log data now).

Answer (score 0):

The redirection is coming from our code because it can't find the page_id of the requesting page.  Why the page_id parameter is gone suddenly on the 25th of July, I can't say yet.